# Prove that logn is O(2^ sqrt(logn))

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, logarithm

I started with log n <= c.2^sqrt(log n) but could not arrive at the desired solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lg(x) < sqrt(x) for large x. Therefore, lg(log n) < sqrt(log n) for large n (substituting log n for x).

Raising 2 to the power of both sides yield the result: log n < 2^sqrt(log n) for large n.

Answer (score 1):

The limit as `n -> inf` of `log n / 2^sqrt(log n)` has to be `!= inf` in order for that to be true.

Apply L'Hospital to get:

```
                             1
                             -
                             n
       -----------------------------------------            =
2^sqrt(log n) * log 2 * 0.5 * (1 / sqrt(log n)) * (1 / n)

                         1
=        --------------------------------            =
  2^(sqrt(log n)) * log 2 * 0.5 * (1 / sqrt(log n))


= let u = sqrt(log n) =

= u / [2^u * log 2 * 0.5]
```

The limit as u approaches infinity of `u / 2^u` is `0`, which proves what we're after.

[Wolfram confirms it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20as%20x%20approaches%20infinity%20of%20log(x)%20%2F%202%5Esqrt(log(x))).

Answer (score 0):

Use variable substitutions, it will be simple.

1. Let `m=lg(n)`, we need to show `m=O(2^sqrt(m))`.
2. Again let `N=sqrt(m)`, now it boils down to showing `N^2=O(2^N)`.
3. Showing the last one is easy since the `polynomials` are bounded from above by the `exponential` functions in terms of growth rate.

Also all the functions we used above are strictly monotonically increasing.